# Requiring a mongoose model results in Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const drugSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    drug_name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A drug must have a name'],
      unique: true,
      trim: true
    }
}
);

const Drug = mongoose.model('Drug', drugSchema);

module.exports = Drug;
```

When I call the displayDrugName function in another file it says -> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of null.

```
const Drug = require('../../models/drugModel');

export const displayDrugName = async drugName => {
  const drug = await Drug.find({ drug_name: drugName });
}
```

Database is on atlas and I've successfully connected to it but why can't I query it?

Comment: Fastest way for you to know what the issue is to wrap the code in the function in `try/catch` and console.log the error in the catch statement... then you can see what the problem is..

Comment: Or you can just do `const drug = await Drug.find({ drug_name: drugName }).catch(err => console.log('Error:: ', err));` to see the error been thrown